# React lazy vs Intersection observer API

Tags: reactjs

I'm a bit confused about the differences between React.lazy and Intersection Observer API.

Are both doing the same thing?

When should I use React.lazy and when should I use Intersection Observer API?

Comment: ["The Intersection Observer API provides a way to asynchronously observe changes in the intersection of a target element with an ancestor element or with a top-level document's viewport."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API), and ["The `React.lazy` function lets you render a dynamic import as a regular component."](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy). The APIs are not related, but you could e.g. use the an Intersection Observer to decide when to dynamically import a component.

Comment: Thanks. Does it mean that before React.lazy I had to use Intersection Observer API to import a component dynamically (only if it's needed), but since React 16.6,  I can do the same thing using React.lazy. Right?

Comment: You don't import anything with the Intersection Observer API at all.